# NSView subviews and types

Tags: objective-c, nsview, xib, nsobject

I have a couple of custom NSBox subclasses called OuterBox and InnerBox. I've set up my view in a XIB and arranged the hierarchy like this:

```
OuterBox : NSBox
    NSButton
    NSBox
    InnerBox : NSBox
    ...and some other views
```

The idea is that when the NSButton gets pressed, in an IBAction method, I want to get the superview of the button and then, from that, get the InnerBox that is in the same OuterBox as the button.

To do this, I loop through the OuterBox's subviews and check their type:

```
for (NSObject *subview in [outerBox subviews]) {
    // this never evaluates to true...
    if ([subview isKindOfClass:[InnerBox class]]) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

The problem is that my `if` statement never hits. `subview` shows up in the debugger as an NSView. According to the documentation, `isKindOfClass:`

> > returns `YES` if the receiver is an instance of aClass or an instance of any class that inherits from aClass, otherwise `NO`.

I understand why it's returning `NO`: because InnerBox is a type of NSView but not vice versa. But I don't know why `subview` is a UIView when it should be an InnerBox.

I have imported InnerBox.h and made sure that the InnerBox really is an InnerBox in the XIB. I don't know what could be causing its type to get changed, or be reported incorrectly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, `isKindOfClass:` should return `YES` when it encounters your `InnerBox`. Perhaps the views aren't nested the way you intended. Two things to check:

1. Is the superview of the `NSButton` truly
   the `OuterBox`? (You could `NSLog` the superview of the sender in your button's action method.)
2. Is the `InnerBox` truly a subview of the
   `OuterBox`? (Perhaps set up an `IBOutlet` to the `InnerBox` and `NSLog` its superview.)

Comment: That was it... either NSButton has an extra superview, or I was passing in one of its subviews... Now, how to get these clumps of hair back onto my head. Glue, maybe...

Comment: Yes, [NSBox is a special case](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Box/Tasks/SettingBoxSubviews.html).